# Good ruby gem sources?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What good ruby gem sources would you recommend, besides http://gems.rubyforge.org/ and http://gems.github.com/? It seems that RubyForge is missing most of the gems I look for these days...

Answer (score 28):

This is now the official RubyGems source:

```
https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 16):

As far as I know, those two are it, with the primary being rubyforge, since that's the only source that a stock RubyGems install will search?  As popular as github is getting, gem developers still can't yet assume that github has been added as a gem source, and usually provide specific instructions like

```
gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
gem install person-gemname
```

or

```
gem install person-gemname --source http://gems.github.com
```

**UPDATE**: gems.rubyforge.org, gems.github.com, and gemcutter.org have all been replaced by     `rubygems.org`

Comment: See also http://gemcutter.org/ which has sprung up since you asked this question.  It bills itself as "the next generation of gem hosting for the Ruby community. Instantly publish your gems and install them."  (I myself don't use it [yet].)

Comment: GemCutter.org has now become "the standard" repository for gems. Github is discontinuing its gem hosting, so go "gem install gemcutter" and then "gem tumble" and you should be rolling.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one from China: http://ruby.taobao.org/

We Chinese users love it because it is much faster than the default two (access from China).

**Update (2015-09-24):**

https is required now, please use https://ruby.taobao.org/

Answer (score 4):

Basically I agree that even if you are hosting projects on github or elsewhere all stable releases should be on RubyForge. The main reason is all the dependancies on gems, and it makes me happy when they are all in one place.

Magnus Holm wrote about this 
http://judofyr.net/posts/dont-forget-about-rubyforge.html

and it was picked up by others as well
http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/08/gems-from-rubyforge-and-github

Answer (score 2):

An alternative in Africa (South Africa in particular):

http://gems.cloudafrica.net/

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to add a RubyForge mirror - however I cannot find one that is up and RubyForge now (10-june-09) is down...